# Automapper Ignore member that's part of a list

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

The source and destination both contain a list. While mapping those lists, the source class is missing doesn't have all of the members that the destination has. This is causing the destination to get set to null rather then retaining the value it had. I've tried ignoring but can't seem to get that working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<info>Information{get;set;}
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<infoDTO>Information{get;set;}
}

public class Info
{
    public string info1{get;set;}
    public string info2{get;set;}
    public string info3{get;set;}
}

public class InfoDTO
{
    public string info1{get;set;}
    public string info2{get;set;}
}
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<info>Information{get;set;}
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<infoDTO>Information{get;set;}
}

public class Info
{
    public string info1{get;set;}
    public string info2{get;set;}
    public string info3{get;set;}
}

public class InfoDTO
{
    public string info1{get;set;}
    public string info2{get;set;}
}


public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    public PersonProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>()
        .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
        .ForMember(d => d.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
        .ForMember(d => d.Information, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Information))

        CreateMap<InfoDTO, Info>()
        .ForMember(d => d.info1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.info1))
        .ForMember(d => d.info2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.info2))
        .ForMember(d => d.info3, opt => opt.opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:
I get the person from the database first, then using the DTO I update the person and save them to the database. To map the person I'm calling:
`_mapper.Map(personDTOUpdated, person);`

Everything I've tried has just resulted in the person's info3 getting set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Something is erroneous with the code you posted here mate. You mapping defines the mapping from Info to InfoDTO. When you say:

```
CreateMap<Info, InfoDTO>();
```

The first clause is always the SOURCE and the 2nd clause is always a DESTINATION. However when you use your mapper (assuming that personDTOUpdated is of type PersonDTO) you are mapping from InfoDTO to Info. You don't have a mapping defined for that scenario. You need to provide a map for PersonDTO -> Person and InfoDTO -> Info.

Also your PersonDTO has a list of Info instances not InfoDTO instances. I don't know if this is just a type or actual coding error but it's something to look at for sure.

Comment: Ah you're writing. I was re-writing/condensing my code to post here and screwed those up. Thanks, fixed now.